# Separate, or not, questions about a result's proof from its Picture and Intuition?

Tags: support

I recently asked two questions of this form, but I'm *not* referring to them; I'm asking in the main about this, for any result.

Say a user wants to ask questions about a result's proof, and also about a picture or intuition of this result. If the user believes that the proof is separate from the picture and intuition, should the user then post two separate questions?

I (lamentably) don't know how to ascertain when a proof is  disjoint from intuition and pictures.

Comment: Would the close-voters care to comment? Neither of the cited reasons make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that in most cases, there should only be one question. This seems to be in the spirit of (1) helping future users and (2) keeping the front page uncluttered.

However, I don't believe that we should attempt to somehow merge old questions asking about one with new questions asking about the other. Also, there are probably edge cases in which one or both of the parts would require exceptional effort on the part of the answerer. Then, I think it is unreasonable to expect someone to answer both simultaneously.

I do think these would be really exceptional cases, though. In particular: if someone is uncertain about whether it is appropriate to ask for both at once, it probably would be.